# How to configure properties or datasources outside of a war or ear

Tags: jakarta-ee

I need to deploy several times the same war or ear in a single container. I will change the names of archives in order to give a different context to each application. I need to pass properties to each war or ear without editing the content of each archive.

Is there any way to this, declare an env-entry outside the ear for example ?

How can I deal with datasources ? Is there any indirection mechanism ?

Answer (score 0):

On Glassfish for instance you can configure the datasources completely within the container context on the admin console. You give them a name (a JNDI name?) and access it through that name from your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't solve my problem. I need to define 2 data sources and assign one to each ear. The two ears use the same datasource so I need an assignment to each ear.

Answer (score 0):

The including mechanist is depends on the using framework.
For example for Spring framework you can use something like this (and put properties file in any classpath folder):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Can you please clarify what framework you are using - it can helps.